# Deviation to weekday and weekend mean on daily data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have some daily data and I wish to compute the deviation of each data point to its monthly mean but I want to distinct the monthly average between weekday and weekend.

some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(100), freq='D')
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = 66*np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))/100
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days, 'vals': data})
df = df.set_index('Date')
print(df)
```

Now if I treated all days equal I can do this:

```
df['valdifftoavg']= df['vals'].sub(df.resample("M")['vals'].transform('mean'))
```

But I want to distinguish, so if the daily data is a weekday substract the weekday average of that month and if its a weekend, substract the weekend average of that month.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
is_weekend = df.index.weekday >= 5

# groupby month and is_weekend
means = (df.groupby([df.index.to_period('M'),is_weekend])
           ['vals'].transform('mean')
        )

df['deviation'] = df['vals'] - means
```